# Access the LAN via VPN

Tags: vpn, local-area-network, wireguard

I've just set up a VPN server on my raspberry pi (using pivpn) and I'd like to be able to directly reach other computers on my local network, remotely. The only computer I'm able to reach, though, is the VPN server itself (the raspberry pi in my case). They only way, as I see it, I could reach other computers on my LAN, is to connect to the SSH server running on the pi and access them "indirectly". Am I missing something? I'm using WireGuard.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you look [at this raspberrypi.stackexchange question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99142/pivpn-client-cant-connect-to-local-network).

Very breifly, you need to setup routing on your Rpi using `iptables` to route the VPN traffic that it receives from your remote client to your local LAN.

Comment: That's not really routing. That is substituting NAPT for routing, which is generally a bad idea.. Properly done, you simply use routing, and if you need to exchange routes, then run a routing protocol between the two ends of the VPN.